# login and linking oath external services to my application

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth, account

I have an application, and i want to offer the possibility to the users to link their accounts (internal myapp account) with other external oauth services (login with facebook, twitter, google, etc) I want to offer the possibility to link an existing account, or login directly with facebook, google, etc (this will create an internal myapp account), any person knows a good tutorial for accomplish this? (preferably in python/php) thank you all!

Comment: Hire someone, SO doesn't work that way, you try something, debug it, search SO, if you failed to find a reliable answer, you ask your question with your written code :) then the community will help you

Comment: i'm asking for a tutorial about a feature (hybrid oauth authentication), internet have a lot of open source system, like (http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/, etc), i'm only asking for a good tutorial, are you kidding me?